# mock $q.resolve(data) in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, promise, karma-jasmine

I have a liner in the service that's using

```
var id = $q.resolve(rid);
```

and when i'm trying to jasmine unit test it, i got an error `TypeError: $q.resolve is not a function`. Here's how i registered `$q`

```
var initService = angular.mock.inject(['service', '$q', '$rootScope', function(_service_, q, rootScope) {
    service = _service_;
    $q = q;
    $rootScope = rootScope;
}]);
```

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: Isn't it `$q.when`?

Comment: you should indeed be using $q.when inside mocks

Comment: No, [you shouldn't](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve), at least if framework version is high enough. In this case it possibly isn't.

Comment: I guess you use $q before it is inited in '$q = q;'